# How shifting stress works in written English?

Tags: writing

Please consider this scenario: I would like to tell someone that if he uses a certain word in his sentence, he would fail to make that sentence absolutely perfect. More specifically, that word would have an adverse effect on the preciseness of the sentence. That said, I also want to assure him that deviation would be so subtle and negligible that he has really got no need to worry about that. So, I tell him this while stressing the word "little":

> If you use that word, you would lose **little** precision.

In another scenario, I would like to tell a person that a word she is to use would make the exactness of the sentence suffer. I want to admit that caused fault of itself is not that significant, but since losing the preciseness is a horrible thing she needs to be worry about that! I finally manage to tell her the same thing I came up with in the previous scenario, but this time, I put stress on the word "lose" or "precision".

> If you use that word, you would **lose** little precision.
>
> If you use that word, you would lose little **precision**.

Now, my question is that does shifting the stress change the meaning of the sentence in the way that I described? If so, how can I illustrate stresses in the writing?

Comment: Shifting the stress does nothing to change the meaning of the sentence you have given (and I'm struggling to think of any example where changing the stress **does** change meaning - except for cases where that stress shifts tone and implied meanings like "**So** nice to meet you.").

Comment: Additionally there is no standardized way (that I can think of) to indicate a change of stress - it is usually done through irregular typography (bold, or italics), irregular spelling "Sooooo nice to meet you" or through altering punctuation.

Comment: @DavidHall Thank you. Then what would you say for the second scenario? The second scenario is meant to inform the person about the lose of preciseness and mention that although the change in precision is small, its negative effect is dramatic.

Comment: "lose little X" implies that the effect is small and  negligible; "lose a little X", with the article, implies that the effect is small but possibly important. You may also say "lose X" (e.g., "lose precision"), which doesn't say how large the effect is but implies that it is important.

Comment: In addition to StoneyB's comment, there are also other words you can use - something like "you would lose some precision". The main problem I see with what you are trying, is that a small change in precision **almost by definition** cannot have a dramatic effect, so you need to introduce a second clause - something like "If you use that word, you only lost a little precision, but that would have a dramatic effect!"

Comment: And after thinking more on the "lose a little X" suggestion from StoneyB, with the article, you can now shift the tone to indicate that losing that precision can be a serious thing. This means you no longer need the second clause. You would not stress any word, but instead use a hesitant or skeptical tone.

Comment: Two big caveats on all this though - there is still no clear way to express these distinctions in written English and (more importantly) these sorts of shifts of meaning using tone and stress can be seriously misinterpreted, even between native speakers, so you need to be very careful with them.

Comment: @DavidHall I'm puzzled by your statement that there is no regular way to indicate change in stress, when you immediately follow by stating the regular way, namely, italics. While use of italics has other meanings and therefore can be ambiguous, it is very widely recognized as indicating stress. When italics are not available, the common convention is to write the stressed word in all capitals.

Comment: @Jay I meant that while both italics and all capitals are common means of indicating a change in stress, neither is formally recognized. If you were to use these in (for example) a university essay, they would (very often) be marked down. My statement was based on the context of an English learners forum - there are dozens of methods commonly used to indicate spoken English, but none are (to my knowledge) are universally accepted.

Comment: @DavidHall Hmm, I don't want to get into an argument about it, so suffice it to say that I disagree. Italics and all-caps are widely recognized as indicating stress or emphasis. It may be true that such use is discouraged in a university essay -- MLB says "Italics for emphasis is ... rarely appropriate in research writing" [MLB, 4th edition,  2.3.3], but there's no indication the OP is writing a university research paper. I searched "show emphasis in writing" and the first hit I got was http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/609/01/ from Purdue university, ...

Comment: ... that recommends italics or underlining. This scholarly looking page, http://www.englishspeaking.org/showing-emphasis/, also recommends italics or all-caps. It's common and widely-recognized. It may be inappropriate to certain very formal writing, but the same could be said of contractions and exclamations.

Comment: For the first one I would say "a little precision" instead of "little precision". The first one means "a bit but not much" whereas the second one means "not much". Just saying "lose little precision" usually means "negligable precision would be lost, so ignore it". Whereas "a little precision" sounds closer to the meaning you described: you are saying that some-but-not-much precision would be lost, and leaving it up to the other person to decide if they want to lose that precision or correct what they said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is certainly true that changes in stress can change the meaning of a sentence.

I'm making up an example off the top of my head so perhaps it's not the best, but consider:

> I want to take my dog to the park.

Simple statement of fact.

> I *want* to take my dog to the park.

I am not being forced to do it, it is not a necessity, but rather it is something that I want to do.

> I want to take my *dog* to the park.

Not my cat, not my girlfriend, but my dog.

> I want to take my dog to the *park*.

Not the store, not the vet, but the park.

Etc. You could stress almost any word in that sentence to alter the meaning.

That said, there's no clear way to express the meaning you want in your example by altering stress. Emphasizing "lose" would imply that someone thought they might gain precision, and so you are making clear that it is not a gain, but a loss. Emphasizing "precision" would indicate that it is precision you are losing and not something else. I'm not sure what that other thing might be.

The best I can see is to add the word "a" before little, and then emphasize "would": "... you *would* lose a little precision." This emphasizes that this is indeed something that will happen, and the presence of "a" means that the emphasis in not on "little" but on "precision".